# How to use chrony to synchronize timestamp on two computers

Tags: networking, ntp, timestamp

I need to compare results which come from two different laptops.
Each laptop has a different set of sensors and in order to correctly compare them I need to have the same timestamp on both laptops.
They are not connected to public internet, but if necessary, I can use a router to make them communicate locally over ethernet.

I installed chrony on both computers, but I didn't understand how to setup the master and how to configure the client.

I've checked these instructions:

```
Master:

driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift
local stratum 8
manual
allow 192.168.165
smoothtime 400 0.01

Clients:

server master iburst
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift
logdir /var/log/chrony
log measurements statistics tracking
```

but I didn't understand if I need to specify these commands in command-line or if I have to create a text file named "drift" containing these instructions and put it inside /var/lib/chrony/ and then restart chrony.

Can you help me, please?
I really cant understand how to use chrony!

Thank you!

Comment: I tried to find some tutorial on Google but I wasn't able to find out how to setup the configuration for the master. Still don't know if I need to create a new file or if I need to modify something else..

Answer (score 3):

the default config in chrony comes with most of this already, no need to change drift or logfile.
Your example pretty much looks like the section "Isolated networks" in `man chrony.conf` so there you can find more details.

The changes you need are all in `/etc/chrony.conf` afterwards restart the service via `systemctl restart chrony`.

In addition to the default config you only need:

a) on master:

```
# make it serve time even if it is not synced (as it can't reach out)
local stratum 8
# allow the IP of your peer to connect (subnet not specific IP)
allow 192.168.XX
```

b) on client:

```
# set the servers IP here to sync to it
server <IP> iburst
# remove the default servers in the config
```

The rest you had in your example is either already in the default configuration or doesn't fit your use case.
For example `smoothtime` will make the served time less jumpy, interesting as you have no high quality clock on your master. But if your use case just wants them **the same** no matter how jumpy, then this is actually not what you want.