# How to know that the chrony works well to synchronize timestamps on two computers?

Tags: networking, sync, ntp, timestamp

I used the chrony to synchronize timestamps on two computers.

The robot's computer is a master and the workstation's computer is a client.

All I did, I follow the question's answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787855/how-to-use-chrony-to-synchronize-timestamp-on-two-computers) after installing the chorny for both computers using

> apt-get install chrony

After that I used this command to measure the latency  as [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/298821/tf-timeout-with-multiple-machines/) did

> ntpdate -q 192.168.xx

.
The output was:

> server 192.168.xx, stratum 3, offset 0.000688, delay 0.03365 12 Nov
> 14:54:28 ntpdate[5375]: adjust time server 192.168.xx offset 0.000688
> sec.

.
And I also got this:

> server 192.168.xx, stratum 3, offset -0.012946, delay 0.04585 12 Nov
> 15:09:38 ntpdate[6213]: adjust time server 192.168.xx offset -0.012946
> sec

Really, It is not familiar to me.

Is it ok or not? if so, what is the range that you judge that it is ok or not?

what is meaning the offset 0.000688 and sometimes offset -0.012946?

I am trying to understand the offset's value sometimes plus and sometimes minus.

please, your help.

Comment: The way you set it up both (robot and workstation) seem to sync to a remote source, you will only see how much your systems differ from that and need to derive how much that means "from each other". Further and more important do not use ntpdate as it will interfere with chrony it is like asking two people to drive. Instead look at `chronyc`  especially subcommands `sources` & `sourcestats` (diff to and quality of sources) and `tracking` (local clock quality).

Comment: Thanks a lot,  I found this link to explain what they are meaning https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Checking_if_chrony_is_synchronized.html